# Что означает слово this в строке?

Tags: java, android

LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

Comment: В учебнике по яве написано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` - это ссылка на самого себя - то есть на экземпляр класса, в котором разворачивается действо.
В вашем случае скорее всего передается контекст текущего activity